# Destructuring Vue 3 reactive nested object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm integrating a JS library into a Vue 3 project. This library provides a hook which is called when the library state changes:

```
let state, api

export function useLibrary() {
  if (!state) {
    const [_state, _api] = init()

    api = _api
    state = reactive({ ..._state })

    api.onState((key, value) => {
      state[key] = value
    })
  }

  return {
    state,
    api
  }
}
```

Then in my component I use `toRefs` to destructure the reactive object. `a` and `b` are primitive types, but the state also includes objects.

```
const { state } = useLibrary()
const {
  a,
  b,
  nestedObject
} = toRefs(state)
```

Reactivity for `a` and `b` work fine. I'm trying to also destructure `nestedObject`:

```
const { c, d } = toRefs(nestedObject)
```

However this doesn't work (the values don't update). In my template if I use `{{ nestedObject.c }}` it updates fine, but I can't seem to destructure it.

Comment: toRefs accepts reactive object, while you're providing it with a ref. Likely should be `toRefs(reactive(nestedObject))`

Comment: @EstusFlask I have the same issue if I pass it `state.nestedObject`, which should already be a reactive object